# Loop through every element in nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] using a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, lambda

I have tried using index . I m having difficulty to understand for loop
how do I access every element of list and append it to empty list.

I have tried this( ps I know I made silly mistake )

```
square = lambda num : num**2
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
square_nums =[]
for i in nums :
    il=nums[i]
    j=square(il)
    square_nums.append(j)
    i+=1
print(square_nums)
```

Comment: Hint: `for i in nums:` iterates over the numbers in the list, *not* their indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct answer using your exemple:

```py
square = lambda num : num**2
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
square_nums =[]
for i in nums :
    j = square(i)
    square_nums.append(j)

print(square_nums)
```

Output:

```py
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

for i in nums : here i is the individual element from the list nums, no need to do i+=1 as i is not the index. Try this:

```
square = lambda num : num*num
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
square_nums =[]
for i in nums :
    j=square(i)
    square_nums.append(j)

print(square_nums)
```

if you want to access using index you can do like this:

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
    print(nums[i])# this will print each element
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're used to programming languages such as C or Java, the way Python handles for loops might come off as a little unorthodox.

As you can see from the answers you already got, at the end of each iteration the variable `i` automatically takes on the value of the next object in the collection you are looping through.
Being that the case, there's no need for you to increase `i` as you would do in other languages. All you have to do is apply the lambda function `square` to each element `i` and append the result to the empty list `square_nums`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like:

```
square = lambda num : num**2
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
square_nums = list(map(square, nums))
```

map() apply function to all items in an iterable, but return a map object so we transform it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, including a one-liner without a for loop.

```
square = lambda num : num**2
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
square_nums =[]
for i in nums :
    square_nums.append(square(i))
print(square_nums)
```

but you also could:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
square_nums = [num**2 for num in nums]
```

if you wanted to use the indices:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
square_nums = []
for i in range(len(nums)):
    square_nums.append(nums[i]**2)
```

if you wanted to use the indice in a while loop instead:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
square_nums = []
i = 0    
while i <= len(nums):
    square_nums.append(nums[i]**2)
    i += 1
```